# Attempting to move files with certain names to a new directory

Tags: python-3.x, shutil

## I am attempting to move files that start with PS-110 to a new folder I created named PS-110.

```py
import shutil, glob, os

files_move = []
files_move = [files_move.append(f) for f in glob.glob('PS-110*.pdf')]

destination = r"C:\Users\kjurgens\Downloads\PS-110"

for f in files_move:
        shutil.move(f, destination)
```

When it runs I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\kjurgens\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\shutil.py", line 771, in move
    if _samefile(src, dst):
  File "C:\Users\kjurgens\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\shutil.py", line 217, in _samefile
    return os.path.samefile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Users\kjurgens\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\genericpath.py", line 100, in samefile
    s1 = os.stat(f1)
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
files_move = [files_move.append(f) for f in glob.glob('PS-110*.pdf')]
```

This doesn't create a list of files, it creates a list full of `None`. This is because `files_move.append(f)` returns None. And you're overwriting `files_move` with the new list by the time this whole execution finished.

Given `glob.glob()` already returns a list, you don't need `files_move` at all.

Just do:

```
import shutil, glob, os

destination = r"C:\Users\kjurgens\Downloads\PS-110"

for f in glob.glob('PS-110*.pdf'):
    shutil.move(f, destination)
```